# R animate ggplot of lat/lon coords using date

Tags: r, plot, jquery-animate, maps

I have a data set with about 180,000 observations.  I can plot all of them using lat/lon coords and ggplot.  When I plot them all at once, i get big blob.  Any tips on how to create an animation, where each frame will plot all of the plots on a given date?  Note that there are often many observations per date.

Thanks in advance

my data has the following columns.

```
Created Date,      Latitude,       Longitude   
     3/19/14,    40.62143617    -73.92598905 
     3/19/14     40.65808826    -73.84443243 
     3/18/14     40.64067217    -73.95307493
```

I used ggplot2 to plot all of the coords with the code below.

```
require(ggplot2)
cold <- read.csv(fn, header=TRUE)
r <- ggplot(cold, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,)) + geom_point(size=.9, alpha=.02)
```

Comment: see the "animation" package.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman - ive been trying to figure out how to use the "animation" package -  most of the posts on the subject are a bit over my head.  My project seems like a pretty simple application, do you know of any basic tutorials?  Thanks

Comment: This question is much too general as is (although I am *not* the one who downvoted it). If you provide a much bigger sample of your data, say 10,000 points across multiple dates, you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: Write a function that plots for a given date. Repeat over dates. Use animation package.

Answer (score 0):

The `tkexamp` function in the TeachingDemos package can be used to make an interactive GUI for your own functions and one of the controls it has an animate control.

Just write a function that takes the date (as a number) as and argument and plots the subset of the data based on that date, then pass that function along with a list specifying the animate control to `tkexamp`.  There will be a slider that you can use to move through time, or click the play button next to the slider and it will scroll through for you.

The last 2 examples for `tkexamp` show using it with ggplot2 and the final example for the `USCrimes` data set (TeachingDemos package) shows using the animate control for `tkexamp`.  Combine these with your data and you will be able to view your data animated.